# Copying a variable with only arithmetic operators

Tags: variables, math, integer-arithmetic, paradox-scripting

What is the best way to copy the value of one variable to another without a direct assignment function?

Variables are 2 byte fixed point numbers with a max value of 2147483.647. The available operators are (reformatted for clarity):

- `add(<variable>, <constant>)` which adds a constant value to the given variable
- `subtract(<variable>, <constant>)` which subtracts
- `multiply(<variable>, <constant>)` which multiplies
- `divide(<variable>, <constant>)` which divides
- `check(<variable1>, <op>, <variable2/constant>)` which compares the value of `variable1` with that of `<variable2/constant>` using the operator `op` and returns a boolean. `op` can be `=`, `<`, `<=`, `>=` or `>`
- `set(<variable>, <constant>)` which sets the value of the variable.
- The scripting language has basic control flow, it has `while` and `if` (but not `else`) as well as basic boolean operators `AND`, `OR`, `NOT` and `NOR`.

Our first attempt was simply:

```
while = {
    count = var1 //loop var1 times
    change_variable = { which = var2 value = 1 } //increment by one
}
```

My next attempt was:

```
set_variable = { which = new value = 1 }
while = {
    limit = { NOT = { check_variable = { which = old value = new} } }
    if = {
        limit = { 
            check_variable = { which = old value > new } 
            check_variable = { which = stage value = 0 }
        }
        multiply_variable = { which = new value = 10 }
    }
    if = {
        limit = { 
            check_variable = { which = stage value = 0 } 
            check_variable = { which = old value < new } 
        }
        set_variable = { which = stage value = 1 }
    }
    if = {
        limit = {
            check_variable = { which = stage value = 1 }
            check_variable = { which = old value < new }
        }
        subtract_variable = { which = new value = 1 }
    }
}
```

E.g., start with 1, multiply by 10 until greater than the target, then subtract 1 until at the target.

But I'm sure there's a much better way to do this.

**Context:**
A recent patch of the scripting language used in the game "Stellaris" has broken the variable assignment function. `set` above should be `set(<variable>, <variable/constant>`). This has broken a lot of existing code, and it's unknown how long it will remain broken.

Comment: Really?!?! Really?!?! Has anyone considered other approaches? Such as rolling back the patch?

Comment: @Mysticial The scripting language is secondary to the game itself. I'm sure it'll be fixed eventually, but they're much more interested in the hundreds of thousands of players than the hundreds of modders.

Comment: This question might be ... "better" suited for https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You should add a language tag

Comment: @MadPhysicist I should create a new language tag for an unnamed language?

Comment: @ThomasBoby. I would

Comment: @MadPhysicist Not enough rep! I would have created "paradox-scripting"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because 2147483.647 is a (power of 2 - 1) /1000 I can use the successive powers of 2 to approach the solution 1 bit at a time: (written in C using only equivalent operations)

```
result = 0;
result +=  1073741.824;
if( var < result )
    result -=  1073741.824;

result += 536870.912;
if( var < result)
    result -= 536870.912;

result += 268435.456;
if( var < result)
    result -= 268435.456;

result += 134217.728;
if( var < result)
    result -= 134217.728;

result += 67108.864;
if( var < result)
    result -= 67108.864;

result += 33554.432;
if( var < result)
    result -= 33554.432;

result += 16777.216;
if( var < result)
    result -= 16777.216;

result += 8388.608;
if( var < result)
    result -= 8388.608;

result += 4194.304;
if( var < result)
    result -= 4194.304;

result += 2097.152;
if( var < result)
    result -= 2097.152;

result += 1048.576;
if( var < result)
    result -= 1048.576;

result += 524.288;
if( var < result)
    result -= 524.288;

result += 262.144;
if( var < result)
    result -= 262.144;

result += 131.072;
if( var < result)
    result -= 131.072;

result += 65.536;
if( var < result)
    result -= 65.536;

result += 32.768;
if( var < result)
    result -= 32.768;

result += 16.384;
if( var < result)
    result -= 16.384;

result +=  8.192;
if( var < result)
    result -=  8.192;

result +=  4.096;
if( var < result)
    result -=  4.096;

result += 2.048;
if( var < result)
    result -= 2.048;

result += 1.024;
if( var < result)
    result -= 1.024;

result += 0.512;
if( var < result)
    result -= 0.512;

result += 0.256;
if( var < result)
    result -= 0.256;

result += 0.128;
if( var < result)
    result -= 0.128

result += 0.064;
if( var < result)
    result -= 0.064;

result += 0.032;
if( var < result)
    result -= 0.032;

result += 0.016;
if( var < result)
    result -= 0.016;

result += 0.008;
if( var < result)
    result -= 0.008;

result += 0.004;
if( var < result)
    result -= 0.004;

result += 0.002;
if( var < result)
    result -= 0.002;

result += 0.001;
if( var < result)
    result -= 0.001;
```

only 32 comparisons needed (less if you can live with less precision or know the upper bound).

Comment: I forgot to mention it does negative,but easy enough to multiply by -1 and do the same. Wow, thanks for this, will try it out!